# A* Search in games

Tags: ai, path-finding

I am making car racing game. I stuck with the `AI` of the game. I go through with the `A*` search, but there is problem that I want to ask that whether we have to make  a `2D` array and than apply search on that array. `2D` array mean a grid, to which we apply the search algorithm.

Can an A* path-finding implementation be practically implemented on data-structures other than a square 2D array?

Comment: That question as edited in by Pieter is interesting, but still too vague to be answerable: What *other data structure* is it that A* should be implemented on? Why would anyone want or need to do this?

Comment: @Anko, the standard data structure that A* is applied to is a general graph, not a 2D grid, and a general graph would be useful anytime you want to do pathfinding in a world that doesn't happen to be shaped like a 2D grid.  IMO this is a specific-enough question at this point and Pieter has answered it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The A* algorithm requires hat the set of possible agent locations be discrete, not continuous, and that there be a **connectivity** relation between the set of possible locations, called **nodes**.

A well-written A* algorithm will not require any particular storage choice for the nodes and the connectivity, but will use **Inversion of Control** to obtain the *adjacent* nodes for each node under consideration from the client.

Eric Lippert has written a very good A* exposition [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/astar/). that can assist you in seeing how this is done.

Comment: Minor issue - A* doesn't have a hyphen in it

Comment: You say "to-mah-to" and I say "to-may-to". I have seen it both ways

Comment: @PieterGeerkens No, Polar is correct - A* written A*, not A-*, in Wikipedia, books, blog posts (including the ones you linked to), etc.  The only place it's written with a hyphen is when writing it out in words, like "A-star".  I've rolled back to Polar's edit correcting it.